# Why model is losing it's binded data in Razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have two questions related to following code
I am binding User in OnGet method which works fine, let's say User.Id is 5 and name is "TestGuy". Then after site is fully loaded and i call OnPost method, User.Id becomes the same as "id" for a product in OnGet parameter i am passing, and User.name is null.
In order to retrieve that user in OnPost i must duplicate code and again query for him trough SignInManager the same way i do that in OnGet, and it feels just wrong.

1. So my first question is: Why this is happening. Why UserModel User is losing his data after page is loaded/? I even tried decorating it with supportGet = true
2. Then second question.
   In OnGet method when i have this line :

   **ProductToBorrow = products[id - 1];**

I must subtract 1 from id to match them because ProductToBorrow.ID is always bigger by 1 than id in products and i cannot understand why. I looked trough my code and there is no code which could cause that addition on ProductToBorrow.

```
   public class RentProductModel : PageModel
    {
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    public RentProductModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    [BindProperty] public ProductModel ProductToBorrow { get; set; } = new();
    public List<ProductModel> UserProducts { get; set; } = new();
    public DateSelector dateSelector { get; set; } = new();
    [BindProperty] public UserModel User { get; set; } = new();



    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Days { get; set; } 
    public ApiManager apiManager { get; set; } = new();


    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetProduct(int id)
    {
        var currentUser = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        var users = await apiManager.GetUsers();
        User = users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == currentUser.UserName);

        var products = await apiManager.GetProducts();
        UserProducts = products.Where(x => x.Lent).Where(p => p.UserId == User.Id).ToList();

         ProductToBorrow = products[id - 1];

        Days = dateSelector.OptionListDays();



        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var currentUser = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        var users = await apiManager.GetUsers();
        User = users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == currentUser.UserName);

        //update product
        ProductToBorrow.Lent = true;
        ProductToBorrow.LoanDateTimeStart = DateTime.Now;
        Convert.ToDateTime(ProductToBorrow.LoanDateTimeEnd);

        ProductToBorrow.UserId = User.Id;
   

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             await apiManager.UpdateProduct(ProductToBorrow);
            TempData["success"] = "Product has been succesfully booked.";
        }


        return RedirectToPage("/Search");


    }
}
```

I added following code but AllProducts have 0 objects in OnPost handler ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWqjV.png))

```
       </div>
        <form method="post">
                @foreach (var product in Model.AllProducts)
                {
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@product.Id"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@product.Type"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@product.Lent" value="false"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@product.LoanDateTimeStart" value="null"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@product.LoanDateTimeEnd" value="null"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@product.Release" value="null"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@product.ReleaseId"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@product.User" value="null"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@product.UserId" value="null"/>
                }
            <div class="m-3"  style="padding: 10px">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" asp-page-handler="Reset">RESET PRODUCTS</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: The data that is available in post is the data that you posted.  If you want the user info to be passed back in the post, those fields must be present in the form and as a param in your post action.  Please include the view (notably the form w/ fields), for a more tailored response, if my statements above do not help your resolve the issue.

Comment: @ hijinxbassist Aha! Thank you very much, that cleared things out regarding to my first question. I added inputs related to User in my form post in view and its working as expected. Question 2 is tho still actuall

Comment: There is not enough detail to answer the 2nd question.  How does the id get set?  If you are letting the database handle the id by using increment, then you 100% should not be using the other id to get this item.  Instead, you should set up a proper relationship in the database.  If you are manually setting the id, then you need to include that code that sets the id.

Comment: ah, now i understand. by encapsulating id in square bracket i indicated that it was an index, not id property and index always starts from 0. Mystery revealed :) Thank you for your help

Comment: @hijinxbassist Can you please tell me if the solution for passing data you described working somehow for List and Collections? I did exactly same thing with my List of products. I added this  <form method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="AllProducts"/>
                <div class="m-3"  style="padding: 10px">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" asp-page-handler="Reset">Reset</button>
                </div>
            </form>  but my list doesnt have any objects. Its empty in OnPost method handler.

Comment: You need to split each item out into a field.  Each item will have the same name.  `<hidden name="myField" value="1"> <hidden name="myField" value="2">` etc. If the item is an object (multiple fields), then you supply an index before the field name.  `<hidden name="myName[0].field1" value="1"> <hidden name="myName[0].field2" value="1"> <hidden name="myName[1].field1" value="1"> <hidden name="myName[1].field2" value="1">` etc.

Comment: @hijinxbassist
thank you for answer. I did as you told but list is still without any object. Please check my answer

Comment: You are creating multiple objects, so you need to follow the 2nd example of using indices.  `"product[0].Id", "product[1].Id"` etc.

Comment: @hijinxbassist
i edited my post. Yes its works indeed but i have to screate form for every single element in every single object in a List. I have just 9 records but what if i have 400?  https://imgur.com/a/H9iSCBB

Comment: Use a for loop instead of foreach, that way you have the index and only need to define the elements once.  You will have to construct the name of the element instead of using asp-for

Comment: Thank you. Its actually working with asp-for but i had to use for-loop. Problem is solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use the following code to pass data to handler:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.AllProducts.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AllProducts[i].Id"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AllProducts[i].Type"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AllProducts[i].Lent" value="false"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AllProducts[i].LoanDateTimeStart" value="null"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AllProducts[i].LoanDateTimeEnd" value="null"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AllProducts[i].Release" value="null"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AllProducts[i].ReleaseId"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AllProducts[i]t.User" value="null"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AllProducts[i].UserId" value="null"/>
                }
```

Comment: Problem is solved. Working fine with for-loop, Thank you!